# Align nav-pill with text

Tags: text, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, nav

What I'm trying to do is align a nav-pill with regular text so that the text in both are on the same line.

Currently, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIm59.png

Here is the code (HTML):

```
<ul class='nav nav-pills'>
    <li class='pull-left'>
        Hello <a>World</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.pull-left {
    float:left;
}
.nav-pills>li>a {
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

How would I make the text's in both be on the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: can you put the code you tried? it would be more convenient than the screenshot.

Comment: `float: left;` ? if they are two separate elements

Comment: I've added the code in the main question. :)